# Уходить и ухаживать

Tags: однокоренные-слова

"Больной
 нуждается в уходе врача, и чем дальше он уходит, тем лучше". В этой 
шутливой фразе как раз обыгрывается схожесть слов "уходить" и 
"ухаживать", а в существительное у них вообще общее "уход". А почему, 
собственно, так? Разные ведь совершенно понятия: заботиться о ком-то и 
покидать что-то. Причем, если во втором случае корень "ход" понятен, то в
 первом - не очень. А еще можно ухаживать за девушкой, то есть, 
оказывать ей знаки внимания.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело, видимо, в этимологии и истории этих слов.

Идти и ходить - разные слова. Идти - двигаться в одном направлении. Ходить - совершать ходы и сам процесс хождения.

У глагола ходити в древности была кратная форма *xadjati (черед. о//а), из неё в результате изменения* dj в ж развилось хажати, давшая хаживать -  ходить когда-то в прошлом, захаживать - изредка ненадолго заходить, выхаживать - долго ходить и ухаживать - ходить за кем-либо, т.е. действовать в чью-либо пользу, заботиться.

В современном у- соединились два разных праславянских слова - au=ou (убрать, увидеть) и   on (удобный, уток, удол-диал.), где у - усилительная приставка, вот она и в слове ухаживать - усердно ходить. Если Вы за кем-то ухаживали, то знаете, как много приходится ходить около него и что-то для него делать, так наухаживаешься, что падаешь к концу дня. И за растениями, животными тоже ухаживать - много и усердно ходить, и за девушкой тоже придётся постараться, а всё связано с хождением.

Answer (score 2):

> "Больной нуждается в уходе врача, и
> чем дальше он уходит, тем лучше".

- Шикарная фраза! А по поводу вопроса - всё довольно просто: ухаживать, значит обхаживать - ходить вокруг да около. Хождение, вхожесть, обходительность, ухажёр - всё это однокоренные слова с общей сутью **ход**. Нет никакого противоречия между хождением и ухаживанием, ведь для того, чтобы оказать знак внимания больному или девушке, к ним следует подойти.

Comment: УхОжёр - тоже прелесть. Чего же он такой голодный?

Comment: Спасибо за внимательное прочтение. Исправлюсь. А вопрос не понял?..

Answer (score 1):

Ухаживать - это подготавливать к переходу в другой мир.

Больной уходит в мир иной, а пока он еще не покинул мир этот, за ним ухаживают.

Жених ухаживая за девушкой тоже стремится увести ее в другой мир, в свой дом. В мифологическом сознании свадьба (особенно для девушки) воспринималась таким же важным событием как рождение или смерть.

Answer (score 1):

*Хотел ответить только Людмиле, но получилось нечто, претендующее на больше, чем простой комментарий. Считайте это моей версией трактовки этимологии этого "ухаживать".*

Строго говоря ходить-уходить-ухаживать представляет собой парадигму вторично имперфектирования по образцу плакать-оплакать-оплакивать, держать-выдержать-выдерживать и т.п.

Но поскольку глагол "ходить" в приставочных формах является супплетивным в отношении категории вида (формы совершенного вида образуются от корня "идти"), а приставочные формы от "ходить" остаются глаголами несовершенного вида, то последнее звено указанного ряда (ухаживать, захаживать и т.п.) остается как бы "не занятым", то ничего удивительного, что оно становится носителем иного смысла.

Так что с этой стороны ничего странного в слове "ухаживать" нет.

Думаю, что вопрос стоит свести к двух значениям современного слова "уход": *от кого?* и *за кем?*. По этому поводу Людмила сказала достаточно, у меня есть только нижеследующий комментарий.

> где у - усилительная приставка,

Разве усилительная? Вроде бы она тут выполняет функцию принадлежности, переноса действия. Да и в других ваших примерах - тоже. "Ухаживать" - это именно ходить **за кем-то** - т.е. то, что сейчас передали бы предлогом "вокруг (кого-то)", или как вы сказали "около". Это же значение, как я понимаю, развилось и в современный предлог "у" (в значении "рядом", "вблизи"). Т.е. еще один вариант передачи исторического состава  "ухаживать" - "ходить у кого-то", "рядом с кем-то". С "усилением" тут как-то не очень...

Вообще-то у приставки "У-" в русском множество значений, а у её предков в праславянском - еще больше. Вплоть до отрицания. Но вот усилительного (в вашем смысле) я что-то не припоминаю...

С остальным - согласен.

Comment: Это древняя приставка с усилит. значением.Упрямый=у+прямой-очень прямой, плохо поддающийся влиянию.Удобный от удобъ = у+ доба(в старослав. "благоприятная пора")- очень лёгкий, благоприятный(исторически однокоренные сдоба, добрый)

Comment: Отсюда ухаживать - очень много , усердно ходить. В современном языке у приставки 5 компонентов значения: "прочь","вниз","маленького размера","для себя","исключительным образом". Идея "исключительном образом", может давать  варианты : "это хорошо" (улучить момент, урвать куш, уберечь, удалось, успеть); "это плохо" (угораздило, урод); "это трудно" (устоять, удержаться, (не)упомнить) "это маловероятно"-"неконтролируемо" (угораздило, уродиться, удалось, угодить<куда-то>, угадать).Ухаживать входит в модель "это хорошо". Так что остатки значения есть и в совр. яз.

Comment: >"исключительном образом",   
  
Вы это значение называете "усилительным"?
Я сейчас навскидку не помню, его, вроде, как-то по другому толковали (в историческом плане, естественно)... Не буду пока спорить, посмотрю источники, если найду время. Не напомните, кстати, где смотреть?